# How to smooth out these 2 perpindicular edges

Tags: bevel

How can I smoothen out this perpendicular edge to multiple smoothed out edges to give it this curve?

### Current

[image: Current]

### Goal

[image: Goal]

I tried beveling but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Try beveling for vertex select those two vertex and SHIFT +CTRL+B.If it doesn't it work switch to object mode click CTRL + A  and  apply scale.The again in edit mode bevel it.

Comment: Good answer. Works perfectly - I only needed one vertex selected when testing.

Comment: Beveling creates a lot of geometry on the other side too: https://imgur.com/PYviPQC

Is there any way I can restrict it specifically to this edge?